# Aggregate entries in table by subset of column id characters

Tags: r

I am working on a gene expression dataset using R.  I am fairly new to coding so please forgive me if I do not describe the problem in adequate detail.

My dataset looks that looks something like this:

```
    GeneID        Sample1    Sample2
    Slc26a5-001   7          8
    Slc26a5-002   1          2
    Homer2-001    6          5
    Slc26a5-200   8          10
```

The gene name is the first part of the ID (Slc26a5) and transcript number is denoted by the (-001).  I need to find a way to collapse all of the different transcript ids together and sum their respective rows at the same time. The output would look like the following:

```
    GeneID        Sample1    Sample2
    Slc26a5       16         20
    Homer2        6          5
```

The Aggregate function should work for summing the rows together based on gene ID. However I am stuck because I can not figure out how to refer to the gene id's by only the first part of their name inside of the aggregate function.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is to remove the tail part of the `GeneID` column so that you standardize the grouping.  This is done below with `sub()`.  Then it's pretty much just standard aggregation. With `aggregate()`, the following will do it.

```
aggregate(df[-1], list(GeneID = sub("-.*", "", df$GeneID)), sum)
#    GeneID Sample1 Sample2
# 1  Homer2       6       5
# 2 Slc26a5      16      20
```

We could also use `rowsum()` and not unnecessarily convert any data.

```
rowsum(df[-1], sub("-.*", "", df$GeneID))
#         Sample1 Sample2
# Homer2        6       5
# Slc26a5      16      20
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(GeneID = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Homer2-001", 
"Slc26a5-001", "Slc26a5-002", "Slc26a5-200"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample1 = c(7L, 1L, 6L, 8L), Sample2 = c(8L, 2L, 5L, 10L)), .Names = c("GeneID", 
"Sample1", "Sample2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi DSS, I used your first answer                                                          aggregate(. ~ cbind(GeneName = sub("-.*", "", rownames(df))), df, sum)                           Thanks!

Comment: Hi DSS - Oh good eye.  I did not notice that at first but you are correct.  Your second solution is better and does not generate that extra column            rowsum(df, sub("-.*", "", rownames(df)))

Comment: @Paul - It would be best to paste the output from `dput(df)` into your question, showing us the exact structure of the data, so we can get this 100% correct.  The data you show has three columns, no row names.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum`.  For easier understanding, here we are splitting it in multiple lines (though it can be done in a single line)

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1)
row.names(m1) <-  sub("-.*", "", row.names(df1))
rowsum(m1, group = row.names(m1))
#         Sample1 Sample2
#Homer2        6       5
#Slc26a5      16      20
```

NOTE: In the unedited OP's post, it was rownames.

---

If it is a `data.frame` with 'GeneID' as a column rather than as `row.names`, then one efficient option with `hadleyverse` would be to `separate` the 'GeneID' column by the delimiter, group by 'GeneID' and get the `sum` of all the columns with `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df2, GeneID, "GeneID") %>%
   group_by(GeneID) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(sum))
#   GeneID Sample1 Sample2
#    <chr>   <int>   <int>
#1  Homer2       6       5
#2 Slc26a5      16      20
```

---

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`), `split` the 'GeneID' by the delimiter, loop through the Subset of Data.table and get the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, lapply(.SD, sum),.(GeneID=tstrsplit(GeneID, "-")[[1]])]
#    GeneID Sample1 Sample2
#1: Slc26a5      16      20
#2:  Homer2       6       5
```

NOTE: The above two solutions will be very efficient

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(GeneID = c("Slc26a5-001", "Slc26a5-002", "Homer2-001", 
"Slc26a5-200"), Sample1 = c(7L, 1L, 6L, 8L), Sample2 = c(8L, 
2L, 5L, 10L)), .Names = c("GeneID", "Sample1", "Sample2"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```